# Subject Alternative Names output not correct in Bouncy castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, subject-alternative-name

I want to add a SAN in bouncy castle and I am using this code:

```
var alt_names = new Dictionary<DerObjectIdentifier, string> {
                    {X509Name.SerialNumber, "334623324234325"},
                    {X509Name.UID, "310122393500003"},
                    {X509Name.T, "0000"},
                    {X509Name.PostalAddress, "Sample E"},
                    {X509Name.BusinessCategory, "Sample Business"}
                };

            var sln = new X509Name(alt_names.Keys.Reverse().ToList(), alt_names);

            var extensions = new Dictionary<DerObjectIdentifier, X509Extension>()
            {
                {X509Extensions.BasicConstraints, new X509Extension(true,
                new DerOctetString(new BasicConstraints(false)))},
                {X509Extensions.KeyUsage, new X509Extension(true,
                new DerOctetString(new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature | KeyUsage.KeyEncipherment
                //| KeyUsage.NonRepudiation)))}
            };

            string certificateTemplateName = "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2";
            DerObjectIdentifier certificateTemplateExtensionOid = new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2");
            DerSequence certificateTemplateExtension = new DerSequence(
                    new DerObjectIdentifier(certificateTemplateName), new DerPrintableString("ZATCA-Code-Signing"));
            extensions.Add(certificateTemplateExtensionOid, new X509Extension(false, new DerOctetString(certificateTemplateExtension)));

            extensions.Add(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, new X509Extension(false,
                    new DerOctetString(sln)));
```

and the output I got it after decoded:

```
Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2: 
                0...+.....7....ZATCA-Code-Signing
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                0x1.0...U....Sample Business1.0...U....Sample E1
0...U....00001.0..
..&...,d....3101223935000031.0...U....334623324234325
```

and the output I need it should be like this:

```
Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2: 
                ..ZATCA-Code-Signing
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DirName:/SN=334623324234325/UID=310122393500003/title=0000/registeredAddress=Sample E/businessCategory=Sample Business
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256

I want to add Subject Alternative names SN, UID, title, registeredAddress and businessCategory as string and beside it the value for each of them and should start with `DirName:` string.
```

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
gen.AddExtension(
    X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName.Id,
    false,
    new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.OtherName, new DerSequence(new Asn1Encodable[] { new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3"), new DerTaggedObject(true, 0, new DerUtf8String(objInput.NombreCertificado)) })))
);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to some narrative context to your solution. Can you give a little more detail as to what was the issue with the OP's question and what they need to change?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).